# removing "read more" from exceprt in wordpress for only one excerpt but not another

Tags: php, wordpress

im just wondering how could I go about removing the "read more" for one particular excerpt and not another in Wordpress. Im also trying to learn php so I figured this is a useful way to learn

I am using `the_excerpt();` within the WP loop in both places.

There is also these lines in the functions.php page

```
function limerickfc_continue_reading_link() {
return ' <a href="'. esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '">' . 
'<br />'.__( 'Read more ',         'limerickfc' ) . '</a>';
 }


function limerickfc_custom_excerpt_more( $output ) {
if ( has_excerpt() && ! is_attachment() ) {
    $output .= limerickfc_continue_reading_link();
}
return $output;
}
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'limerickfc_custom_excerpt_more' );
```

so am I right in saying `limerickfc_custom_excerpt_more` is added to `get_the_excerpt` every time its called? Is it possible to remove this filter as a once off in the loop where I dont want 'read more'
I tried `remove_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'limerickfc_custom_excerpt_more' );` within the loop but no luck.

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: If you know the id of the post, you can add a logic to exclude the `Read More`

Comment: Thanks, but wont that not be applied to that post whereever the excerpt is called? And so it will exclude it where I actually do want it?

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution by any means, but I ended up just simply hiding it by having the excerpt text in a div that ends right underneath the text. And then a css style, `overflow:hidden` to stop the read more link from being seen.